# XPath in Postgres for multiple root nodes with same name

Tags: xml, postgresql, xslt, xpath

I have the following situation. This is the XML:

```
<Detect>
        <Flag>
        Yes
        </Flag>
        <Fraud_Alert_Code>
        3006
        </Fraud_Alert_Code>
        <Flag>
        No
        </Flag>
</Detect>
```

I use the following query:

```
xpath('//Detect/Flag/text()', response ::xml) as Flag
```

But it doesn't return anything. It works for other values in the query. The only question here is: Is it because there are 2 root nodes with the same names? And, if yes, how can I separate them?

I tried using `Flag[1]` and `text[1]` and in combinations.. but nothing works..

Comment: I am not familiar with PostgreSQL. What does `response ::xml` mean? That the result should be XML?

Comment: Response is the name of the column in the database in which this xml was stored. It doesnt have any bearing on the out put of the xml.

Comment: Your XML has only one root (or document element), namely `Detect`. It is absolutely legitimate to have more than one `Flag` element. Are there namespaces in the document?

Comment: What is the type of `response` before casting? If it is character data of some sort then you could be converting it as a document fragment, not a complete document, which may cause issues with the query staring with `//`. Does using something like `xpath('//Detect/Flag/text()', XMLPARSE(DOCUMENT response))` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your xpath query [works](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/3048).

[`xpath()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-xml.html#FUNCTIONS-XML-PROCESSING) returns `xml[]` (or `xml array`), so you could use [array indexing](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html#ARRAYS-ACCESSING), to access each element. But note, that each element is an `xml` (actually a [content fragment](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-xml.html), which contains only text nodes in your case), so you might need to cast it to `text` (or cast the whole result of the `xpath()` call to `text[]`) to get their text content.

Also:

- you can't have multiple [root nodes](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#i-Document); your root **element** is `Detect`
- starting your xpath with `//` makes your query not to care about the root element at all: it will find any `Flag` element, which is a child of any `Detect` element.

Comment: Actually, the *root node* is `/`, `Detect` is the *root element*.